# Blazor webassembly storing auth0 secrets

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

For Blazor Server I store Auth0 settings for an API I consume using AWS Parameter Store.

I want to store secrets for a Blazor web assembly app and everywhere tells me that you shouldn't store any user secrets because it is downloaded by the client.

Thats all fine - I get why - but I need to interact with my API which requires Auth0 keys etc. - so where do I store/use these keys for my web assembly app?

Comment: Where would you "store" them if you were building a React or Angular application? Porbably nowhere. Blazor WASM is actually React# - the component model is *identical*, the security issues the same.

Comment: Without looking how SPAs do this I'd say you shouldn't store secrets anywhere. Tokens, provided by the server maybe, if they're refreshed frequently and there's a way to prevent replay attacks. I'd look how React and Angular solve the same problem though and replicate it. After all, the browser environment is the same

Comment: Yeh I understand that. So how does a client-side app authenticate with other API's if you cannot store the keys?

Comment: I'd research it first. Nobody knows everything or can remember it all the time

Comment: If you are okay with the end user knowing the keys then let the client have them. If not then you have to send the request to your server and have it execute it (calling other APIs if necessary).

Comment: Found this article so will give this a try. https://auth0.com/blog/securing-blazor-webassembly-apps/ - uses TokenProvider to get an accesstoken.

Comment: For securing client side you can use oidc code flow without exposing any secret key. Blazor has support for oidc. So it is not so hard to configure. Additionally I would recommend to use code flow with PKCE.
More info on oidc PKCE: https://oauth.net/2/pkce/

How to setup Blazor for oidc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio